# Customer JQuery Dialog Syntax Error

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a alert messaqge using jquery dialog. Hiding title and auto close.

function MotoAdresCartMessage(msg, miliseconds) {

```
var div = $('<div>').html(msg).dialog({
    height: 75,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        setTimeout($(this).dialog(), miliseconds);
    },
    dialogClass: "noclose",
})

$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

}

it hasent got syntax error and it shows the message

Error

SCRIPT1007: Expected ']'

Comment: This error is caused by some other code in your script. most likely by a an object. Check your syntax.

Comment: Sam is probably right, but there is also a trailing comma after "noclose", which can cause problems in js.

Comment: i think problem giving on  setTimeout($(this).dialog(), miliseconds); and  $(this).dialog()
maybe jquery cant access the object on initializing

Comment: when i change $(this).dialog() to "$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close')"


0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'